# Postfix reject unknown recipients during the SMTP transaction

Tags: postfix

We run Postfix mail server. It's postfix + spamassasin + cyrus + MailScanner +MySQL. Primary mail server is used by one domain (example.com) (two domains in total). Postfix is using MySQL for virtual domains and users. Also I have rewrited one domain `example.com` to `example.biz`.

Server is set up (configured) about 7 years ago. Here is [postconf -n](https://gist.github.com/imojams/03e86e3187518c8dcb4e94b205da486d)

Problem is that in logfile I see some `random recipients` to virtual domain. I read [Postfix Backscatter Howto](http://www.postfix.org/BACKSCATTER_README.html#random) and [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/792442/postfix-reject-not-bounce-unknown-virtual-aliases). At this moment server is sending back Delivery Status Notification to that senders. I tried various configurations but without luck. Here is output from smtp log

```
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: >>> CHECKING RECIPIENT MAPS <<<
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key randomuser@example.com
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: maps_find: recipient_canonical_maps: randomuser@example.com: not found
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: match_string: example.com ~? mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-mydestination.cf(0,lock|fold_fix)
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: dict_mysql_get_active: attempting to connect to host unix:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: dict_mysql: successful connection to host unix:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: dict_mysql: successful query from host unix:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: dict_mysql_lookup: retrieved 0 rows
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: match_list_match: example.com: no match
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: maps_find: recipient_canonical_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/myrecipientmap(0,lock|fold_fix): @example.com = @example.biz
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: mail_addr_find: randomuser@example.com -> @example.biz
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: smtpd_check_rewrite: trying: permit_inet_interfaces
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: permit_inet_interfaces: mail-lf0-f51.google.com 209.85.215.51
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: before input_transp_cleanup: cleanup flags = enable_header_body_filter enable_automatic_bcc enable_address_mapp
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: after input_transp_cleanup: cleanup flags = enable_header_body_filter enable_automatic_bcc enable_address_mappi
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: connect to subsystem public/cleanup
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: queue_id
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: input attribute name: queue_id
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: input attribute value: 6564E15F890
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: input attribute name: (end)
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: send attr flags = 50
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: 6564E15F890: client=mail-lf0-f51.google.com[209.85.215.51]
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: > mail-lf0-f51.google.com[209.85.215.51]: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 postfix/smtpd[29764]: < mail-lf0-f51.google.com[209.85.215.51]: DATA
```

At log I see, that random user not found in database `dict_mysql_lookup: retrieved 0 rows`. So, that's correct. But it isn't rejected at SMTP level. Obviously something is wrong with [my config](https://gist.github.com/imojams/03e86e3187518c8dcb4e94b205da486d).

I tried adding virtual user lookup at `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` directive and changed `permit` to `reject` but without luck.

What I want to do then is change the postfix behaviour so that, instead of generating a bounce email form MAILER-DAEMON the mail is rejected during the SMTP transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that while you don't have such an account under virtual domains in mysql, you actually have for some reason set canonical map for this domain:

```
postfix/smtpd[29764]: maps_find: recipient_canonical_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/myrecipientmap(0,lock|fold_fix): @example.com = @example.biz
```

Canonical(5) manual explicitly states that:

```
@domain address
          Replace other addresses in domain by address.  This form has the
          lowest precedence.

          Note: @domain is a wild-card.  When  this  form  is  applied  to
          recipient  addresses,  the  Postfix SMTP server accepts mail for
          any recipient in domain, regardless of  whether  that  recipient
          exists.   This  may  turn  your  mail  system into a backscatter
          source: Postfix first accepts mail for  non-existent  recipients
          and  then  tries  to  return that mail as "undeliverable" to the
          often forged sender address.
```

In short, you should stop using this form of aliasing in canonical maps and use virtual alias maps for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I try to change configuration in several days and then report it back.

Comment: If I remove recipient_canonical_maps then blocking is working at smtp level. But then domain rewrite not working anymore. We have primary domain `example.com` After some time we registred another domain `example.biz` and rewriting example.biz to example.com

Comment: I added domain rewrite in `canonical_maps`, that works but in this way it accepts mails for random accounts to :(

Comment: If you need to rewrite domain part AND keep recipient validation before queue, you need to add individual address aliases for your existing virtual domain users into virtual_alias_maps. Any form of @domain on the left side of the lookup will turn off recipient validation in postfix.

Comment: That looks like. I already tried adding various rewrites and unknown accounts still is accepted. Thanks Peter.